# How to identify selection from comma delimited list parameter in AWS Cloud Formation Template

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, aws-cloudformation

I am fairly new to AWS and still learning, but I have a parameter using CommaDelimitedList as the type in a CFT, so the user can select the subnet to use on a VPC. I need to be able to reference the selection later on when creating the EC2 instance and assigning a private IP.

```
"SubnetParameterCidrBlock":{
    "Description": "Comma-delimited list CIDR blocks for VPC",
    "Type" : "CommaDelimitedList",
    "Default": "10.200.1.0/24,10.200.2.0/24,10.200.3.0/24"
}
```

I would assume that I would I could do something like:

```
"NetworkInterfaces": [
      {
        "DeleteOnTermination": "true",
        "Description": "Primary network interface",
        "DeviceIndex": 0,
        "SubnetId": {"Ref": "SecureVPCSubnet"},
        "PrivateIpAddresses": [
          {
            "PrivateIpAddress": "Fn::GetAtt" : [ "SubnetParameterCidrBlock" , "Value" ],
            "Primary": "true"
          }
        ],
        "GroupSet": [
          {
            "Ref": "SecurityGroup"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
```

Is this correct or do I have this all wrong?

I have been through most of [AWS Cloud Formation Docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/Welcome.html). Are there any other docs out there that give better examples?

Answer (score 1):

You should try using the `Fn::Select` AWS CFT function. Take a look [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-select.html) for a start.. ;)

Comment: Unfortunately, Fn::Select requires I know which one they have selected. That is the problem I am trying to solve. I know the whole list, I just don't know which one they selected in the parameter options.

Comment: Well, if I understand correctly and you just need to access the value of the parameter, how about you try `{ "Ref": "SubnetParameterCidrBlock" }` ?